# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate XX bytes)

Tags: php, memory-limit

Initially, it was stated in the settings of 128MB, then I got this error, I thought that maybe did not have enough memory, then I increased to 256MB, but the error continues.

String in code with this error:

```
function clean($str) {
$clean_str = stripslashes (trim($str));
return $clean_str;
}

// clean slashes
foreach($result[$i] as $key=>$value) {
 if($key=="currency") continue;
 $result[$i][$key] = clean($result[$i][$key]);
}
```

Why is this happening ?

Comment: What exactly does `$str` contain?

Comment: i added in question code from other file, where function clean called. Variable $key =  fields name from DB with values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your `php.ini` to increase your `memory_limit` to something higher than what you have currently provisioned – 512MB is not unusual for modern day applications.

Comment: Did you try it? Does raising the `memory_limit` work?

Comment: Nope, i deleted this code. It's not my CMS and i think is excess code.

Comment: Nope... what? First, did you try it? Second, if you tried it, did it work?

Comment: Well, do what you like, then.

Comment: Sometimes, I have more fun on stackoverflow than most humor sites on the web.

Answer (score 0):

256MB (the default these days, and the amount that 268435456 bytes amounts to), is a lot of memory for a script, so if you're exceeding it, the first things to check for are a few scenarios:

An infinite loop will exhaust the memory limit:

```
var $storage = null;
while(true){
  $storage += 'infinity!'; // Or something even more resource requiring.
}
```

Alternatively, if you are pulling data from a database and accidentally pull too much from a table with a lot of data, and no limit in the sql statement, that can exhaust your php script memory:

```
select * from users where true; // On a million-row table, this could do it.
```

So in general, this message is about the script exhausting it's memory, but it's usually not a call to raise the limit so much as a call to figure out why your script is misbehaving.

Comment: This error also occurs on recursion: ``function foo() { foo(); }; foo();``.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting these errors all of a sudden about a day and a half ago in my error logs when trying to activate plugins. Which was causing blank/white screens.

**"mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 491520 bytes) in wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/lib/W3/ConfigKeys.php on line 1329"**

**"mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 491520 bytes) in wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/lib/W3/ConfigKeys.php on line 1329"**

upping the memory_limit in the php.ini or .htaccess did not fix the issue for me. I had to go into the php settings for the domain and turn the safe mode option from "default" or "off" to "on" using Plesk.

Comment: Hey, you mean that setting safe mode to on, fixed the original issue?